# Maximum call stack size exceeded in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR0rh.png)

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Call Stack
String.replace
<anonymous>
```

I am receiving this error when inserting the element "ConversationList" inside the given code in layout.tsx

```
export default async function ConversationsLayout({children} : {children : React.ReactNode}) {
   const conversations = await getConversations();
   console.log("layout",conversations);

   return (
      <Sidebar >
          <div className='h-full'>
              <ConversationList
                initialItems={conversations}
              >
                {children}
              </ConversationList>
              
          </div>
      </Sidebar>
   )   
}
```

and the "ConversationList" component is like this:

```
'use client';

import { ConversationType } from "@/models/conversationModel";

interface ConversationListProps {
    initialItems: ConversationType[];
}

const ConversationList : React.FC<ConversationListProps> = ({initialItems}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        Conversation List!
    </div>
  )
}

export default ConversationList
```

I can't understand where am I calling a recursive function that is causing this call stack exceed error

I tried to add and remove the "ConversationList" component . The code works fine without the ConversationList component but it is not working with this component.

Comment: Images of errors are not nearly as useful as the actual text of the errors.